# How to set this switched capacitor filter's cut off frequency?

Tags: active-filter

I have never used one and if I'm not wrong, [this](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX293-MAX297.pdf) low pass switched capacitor filter is supposed to have tunable roll-off frequency.

[image]

If we use the above configuration with a particular clock frequency, what is the formula leading to cut-off frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet: For 293 and 294, clock is 100x corner frequency. For 297, clock is 50x.